# Twitter bootstrap 3 - vertical align columns in a row [middle]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I see bootstrap do not fix the height of the columns in the row. For example: image 1:1, it will be responsive in the column, but the position of the image is at the top of the row.

If I have text in `heading` tag, It have default margins that pushes the text below. So the image will be bonded to the top and the text will be little below the top.

What if I need to normalize the columns and make it aligned in the middle?

**My questions is:**

- Is there a native bootstrap way to align the columns?
- If it not support this kind of alignment, what "hack" I can use? I Tried some "hacks" but they affect the base bootstrap functionality.

**What exactly I need to do:**

Sorry but it's hard to make it in a jsfiddle, It's includes Angular directives and templates. Just for example:

I have a directive which generates this:

[image: Not aligned]

I need to do align the image in the middle, or at least to be at the `heading` vertical start. For example: 
[image]

I made this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ifch0o1/8h3pjugb/) if you want to experiment. I accept just explanations without any code.

I can fix it with some "hacked" css, but I wanna know how I can do that the right way.

Comment: As far as I've heard, there isn't a native `vertical-align` setting in Bootstrap, you have to use custom CSS. There are actually a lot of answers to this question... I found 6 SO answers just by searching "Bootstrap middle align", so you should check those out.

Comment: I see this is common. As I said i tried some custom css, but it affect the bootstrap element positioning at all. If you know the good way, that works right and didn't affect the other functionality could you show me just the link, where I can read about it?

Comment: I don't know a specific way to do it, and I don't have time today to experiment on your example (work is almost over.) If it hasn't been answered by tomorrow, I'll look more into it in depth. Sorry about that.

Comment: @TimLewis - It's no problem, I going to sleep after few minutes. Just asked you for a source that I can read. Just I found so many text about this, and most of this text (all that I have tested) It's not working right. Thx anyway. Do not try to lose your time with researches if you already don't know any post that explains the problem. This is my work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One approach is to use translateY on the `img` element like this:

```
.v-center {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

You'll also want to put the image inside a `col-*-2`..

**Demo:** http://bootply.com/tVyuhaFoww

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. The `transform` property will work great in most cases. I am so sleepy and I going to sleep right now. Tomorrow I will check it in-depth. If no better answer I'll accept that. **I really like it.**

Comment: @ish2f4f You don't need to put the edit summary in the post.

Comment: yeah i figured -- @approxiblue it was giving me a min character error though not sure what the right way to go about it was then. esp since the edit seemed important though it only changed one character

Answer (score 2):

Another way to align the image at the top of the first paragraph is to break your design into two rows.   The first row contains the header and the second row contains the image, paragraphs and links.  This closely resembles your second image above, if that's the way you want it to look.

http://jsfiddle.net/404vska2/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-push-2">
    <h4 class="ng-binding">Monaco make Bernardo Silva move permanent</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <img src="http://s12.postimg.org/gt71dlbd5/1421893782_flat_world_cup_icon_512_Socker_1.png" alt="" class="col-xs-2">
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <p class="ng-binding">Bernardo Silva's loan move from SL Benfica to AS Monaco FC has been made permanent, with the 20-year-old settling in well since his summer switch to France.</p>
    <span class="rss-news-date ng-binding">Jan 21, 2015</span>
    <p><a ng-href="http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2204161.html?rss=2204161+Monaco+make+Bernardo+Silva+move+permanent" href="http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2204161.html?rss=2204161+Monaco+make+Bernardo+Silva+move+permanent">Lean more</a> </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This can be used in some different cases. I agree that using the grid system is better way than using custom CSS. Just in my case this have a drawback - If the heading have more than one line text, the image will be pulled down. The sameness with the other sibling elements will be lost. However, this will work perfect in some other cases. I like the idea.